# Set Android Things time zone

Tags: timezone, settings, raspberry-pi3, android-things

After installing Android Things on a Raspberry Pi, time is not correct. My time zone is GMT+2, and using `date +%Z` I see RPi's time zone is GMT. How can I set time zone?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41342845/6950238) question and answers.

Comment: I don't want only set time. I want to set time zone.

Comment: `adb shell settings put global time_zone Europe/Madrid` didn't work?

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work :(

Comment: and `AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setTimeZone("Europe/Madrid");` from `apk` with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes, it worked :) You should post an answer, and I'll select as the correct one

Comment: Please see the answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update (based on [Michal Harakal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211886/michal-harakal)'s comment):**

Since [Developer Preview 6](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/android-things-developer-preview-6.html) [`TimeManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/device/TimeManager) class provides access to device settings related to time (NB! `TimeManager` requires `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.SET_TIME" />`). You can use [`.setTimeZone()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/device/TimeManager#setTimeZone(java.lang.String)) method of for time zone set:

```
private void setupTimeZone(String timeZoneName) {
    TimeManager timeManager = TimeManager.getInstance();
    timeManager.setTimeZone(timeZoneName);
}
```

where `timeZoneName` is one of [tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) string, e.g. for [Kyiv](https://www.google.com.ua/maps/@50.450467,30.5224943,8z?hl=en) (GMT +2, DST +3):

```
setupTimeZone("Europe/Kiev");
```

**Original answer:**

You can set it programmatically from Application via [`AlarmManager.setTimeZone()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setTimeZone(java.lang.String)) like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27540304/6950238) answer of [Synesso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45525/synesso):

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setTimeZone("Europe/Madrid");
```

with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

List of [TimeZone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) names.

Comment: This is not working on Android Things DevPreview 5.1 "setTimeZone: Neither user 10031 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" eventough I added the permission in the manifest. Any idea?

Comment: @MRodrigues Did you reboot device?

Comment: Yeah, also did tried that. Next execution after boot same error .

Comment: I've the same problem ... actually i can't set a timezone on Android Things API 27 application ! Is that possible ?

Comment: @cicciosgamino with DP6 has Google Introduced a new API for setting time. Have a look on TimeManager https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/device/TimeManager.html

Comment: How to import TimeManager class

Comment: @DivyanshuKushwaha Just add `import com.google.android.things.device.TimeManager;` to your class, but Android Studio do this automatically by defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I use these codes

```
TimeManager timeManager = TimeManager.getInstance(); 
timeManager.setTimeFormat(TimeManager.FORMAT_24);
// Set time zone to Eastern Standard Time
//timeManager.setTimeZone("America/New_York");
timeManager.setTimeZone("GMT");
calendar.setTime(date);
long timeStamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
timeManager.setTime(timeStamp);
```

with this permission :
com.google.android.things.permission.SET_TIME