# How to set time zone on Android Things rp3?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I would like to change timezone on AndroidThings device on Raspberry PI3. I have already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537239/set-android-things-time-zone) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342845/how-to-change-the-date-on-android-things-device) . This last one using `adb date somedate` works, but after losing power, the date resets itself.

Is there anyway that we could set timezone from Java or running a shell? The required Timezone of the device is received from server.

Comment: While trying to achieve the dynamic timezone I found at that I can set timezone permanently trough shell command with root privileges: `setprop persist.sys.timezone "Atlantic/Madeira`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With DP6 you can use the TimeManager API without requesting for the permission in the manifest.

```
new TimeManager().setTimeZone(String timezone)
```

Comment: Great need to test that out!

Comment: I'm trying this but i get the following error :                                         
  Calling process requires permission 
  com.google.android.things.permission.CHANGE_TIME

Comment: You need to restart your RPi with the "IOT_LAUNCHER" in the manifest. This permission is only granted on device start.

Answer (score 0):

For now on android Things 5.1 Devpreview the only way I found out to be able to change timezone dynamically trough Java is using command shell:

```
String command = "setprop persist.sys.timezone Atlantic/Madeira". 
try{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
}catch(IOException e){
    //Deal with the exception according to your priest teachings
}
```

You can check new date on adb `adb shell date` or on runtime by instanciating a Datetime object.

Let me know if you find out a better way!